# Only print when last occurred in XML using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a similar XSLT like below:

```
<Records>
 <Record>
  <Name>James</Name>
  <Subject>Maths</Subject>
  <Marks>75</Marks>
</Record>
<Record>
 <Name>James</Name>
 <Subject>Physics</Subject>
 <Marks>68</Marks>
</Record>
<Record>
 <Name>Alex</Name>
 <Subject>Maths</Subject>
 <Marks>89</Marks>
</Record>
<Record>
 <Name>Alex</Name>
 <Subject>Chemistry</Subject>
 <Marks>73</Marks>
</Record>
```

Now I want to print subtotal of each Name only at the last occurrence, For example, I want to print 143 as subtotal for James at the last occurrence i.e., when subject is Physics.
something like below:

```
<Records>
 <Record>
  <Name>James</Name>
  <Subject>Maths</Subject>
  <Marks>75</Marks>
  <SubTotal />
 </Record>
 <Record>
  <Name>James</Name>
  <Subject>Physics</Subject>
  <Marks>68</Marks>
  <SubTotal>143</SubTotal> <!-- Total marks of James -->
 </Record>
 <Record>
  <Name>Alex</Name>
  <Subject>English</Subject>
  <Marks>89</Marks>
  <SubTotal />
 </Record>
 <Record>
  <Name>Alex</Name>
  <Subject>Chemistry</Subject>
  <Marks>73</Marks>
  <SubTotal>162</SubTotal> <!-- Total marks of Alex -->
 </Record>
</Records>
```

What would be the XSLT logic for this scenario? I'm very new to XSLTs and I have tried everything that I could but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: This is a [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info) question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here.

Comment: Do note that the Muenchian method provides an easy way to identify the last member of a group (although usually it is used to point at the first one), as well as aggregating the group's values.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm not trying to group based on the name in my scenario. I  want the same structure with an additional element in the last occurrence of the student.

Comment: If you want a subtotal for each name, the you definitely *are* trying to group by name - even if there is no wrapper element for the group in your output.

Comment: But how do I only print it at the last occurrence? (Sorry, if my queries are really basic. I just started working on xslts a week ago)

Comment: You can use `<xsl:if test="count(. | key('rec-by-name', Name)[last()]) = 1">` (after defining the grouping key as explained here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

Comment: For a beginner I will not throw him immediately into the Muenchian complexity. There is at least one non-Muenchian solution that I know (based on sequential identity) that will be even more efficient than using Muenchian grouping, given the specific ordering of the elements in the XML document provided by @Nithin.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**I. For an XSLT beginner, here is a solution  that doesn't use keys (but it would be less efficient than the one with keys**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match= "Record[not(Name = preceding-sibling::*[1]/Name)][position() > 1]">
    <SubTotal><xsl:value-of select=
    "sum(preceding-sibling::*[Name = current()/preceding-sibling::*[1]/Name]/Marks)"/></SubTotal>
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match= "Record[position() = last()]">
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    <SubTotal><xsl:value-of select=
    "sum(preceding-sibling::*[Name = current()/Name]/Marks) + Marks"/></SubTotal>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Records>
    <Record>
        <Name>James</Name>
        <Subject>Maths</Subject>
        <Marks>75</Marks>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Name>James</Name>
        <Subject>Physics</Subject>
        <Marks>68</Marks>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Name>Alex</Name>
        <Subject>Maths</Subject>
        <Marks>89</Marks>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Name>Alex</Name>
        <Subject>Chemistry</Subject>
        <Marks>73</Marks>
    </Record>
</Records>
```

**The wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Records>
   <Record>
      <Name>James</Name>
      <Subject>Maths</Subject>
      <Marks>75</Marks>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Name>James</Name>
      <Subject>Physics</Subject>
      <Marks>68</Marks>
   </Record>
   <SubTotal>143</SubTotal>
   <Record>
      <Name>Alex</Name>
      <Subject>Maths</Subject>
      <Marks>89</Marks>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Name>Alex</Name>
      <Subject>Chemistry</Subject>
      <Marks>73</Marks>
   </Record>
   <SubTotal>162</SubTotal>
</Records>
```

**Note**: A more advanced non-keys solution that is as efficient or even more than a keys-based one will use the [**"sequential identity" transformation**](https://www.biglist.com/lists/lists.mulberrytech.com/xsl-list/archives/200509/msg00801.html) and pass the current running total as a parameter. (See **Part III**. below). Here is the code of this not-so-well-known identity transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="/node()[not(self::*)]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**II. Using the** **[Muenchian method for grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:key name="kByName" match="Record" use="Name"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Record[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kByName', Name)[last()])]">
     <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
     <SubTotal><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kByName', Name)/Marks)"/></SubTotal>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document, again the same, correct result is produced**.

---

**III. A non-key solution using the so called "sequential identity:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
   <xsl:param name="pAccum" select="0"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/node()[not(self::*)]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Record[Name = preceding-sibling::*[1]/Name]">
   <xsl:param name="pAccum" select="0"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]">
      <xsl:with-param name="pAccum" select="$pAccum+ Marks"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match=
     "Record[preceding-sibling::* and not(Name = preceding-sibling::*[1]/Name)]">
   <xsl:param name="pAccum" select="0"/>
     <SubTotal><xsl:value-of select="$pAccum "/></SubTotal>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]">
      <xsl:with-param name="pAccum" select="Marks"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Record[not(preceding-sibling::*)]">
   <xsl:param name="pAccum" select="0"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]">
      <xsl:with-param name="pAccum" select="$pAccum +Marks"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Record[not(following-sibling::*)]">
   <xsl:param name="pAccum" select="0"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
     <SubTotal><xsl:value-of select="$pAccum + Marks "/></SubTotal>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @michael.hor257k, For a beginner I will not throw him immediately into the Muenchian complexity. There is at least one non-Muenchian solution that I know (based on sequential identity) that will be even more efficient than using Muenchian grouping, given the specific ordering of the elements in the XML document provided by the OP